# variable defined with a command (for exemple a random value) is not correctly stored in a lua list

Tags: luatex, expansion, random

I am writing random exercices for all students in a class, and i want to store the solutions to print them all at the end of the document (in final versions, each question will be printed in a dedicated page, and all solutions will be printed in a separate page).

I use lualatex to store and print the solutions. In the following MWE, the macro `\hide{}` fails to store the variables `\student`,`\a`,`\b` and `\c`, so they are not recovered in the `\solutions` macro.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor} % for 'foreach' loop
\usepackage{xfp} % for '\fpeval'
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{luacode} % for '\luastringN' and '\luaexec' macros
\directlua{ anslist ={}; }

\ExplSyntaxOn
% defining \hide
\cs_set:Npn \hide #1 { 
   \directlua{ table.insert(anslist,\luastringN{#1}) }
   \phantom{ #1 }
}
% defining \addanswer
\cs_set:Npn \addanswer #1 {
   \directlua{ table.insert(anslist,\luastringN{#1}) }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\def\solutions{
    \luaexec{%
        for i,v in ipairs(anslist) do
            tex.sprint ( v )
        end }
}

\begin{document}

\textbf{questions:}\\

\foreach \student in {student1,student2,student3} {
\edef\a{ \fpeval{(randint(1,9)) } }
\edef\b{ \fpeval{(randint(1,9)) } }
\edef\c{ \fpeval{ \a+\b } }

question for \student: $\a+\b= ?$ \newline
\hide{answer for \student: $\a+\b= \c$ \\[5mm]}

}

\textbf{solutions:}\\

\solutions

\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't get your code to compile successfully on my system (MacTeX2021; LuaHBTeX Version 1.13.2; LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1): It terminates with `! Undefined control sequence.  \student`. Please fix.

Comment: _macros_ are not _variables_ ! You store  `\student`, `\a`, `\b` and `\c` as unexpanded macros...

Comment: @Paul Gaborit I thought that defining \a with \edef would expand it. I guess that i should use some \expandafter, but i have no idea where to put it. I tried with
`\expandafter\directlua{ table.insert(anslist,\luastringN{#1}) }`
but it also failed to compiles.

Comment: @Mico You're right, i precisely need to fix this expansion problem (see message of Paul Gaborit) to make it compile.

Comment: Use `\luastring` (instead of `\luastringN`)...

Comment: @Paul Gaborit You're right, the code of this MWE now compiles and gives the expected result. Curiously, this solution breaks my more complex codes. I have no time to do it now, but i will try to isolate and solve the now problem, and maybe i will post here another solution. If you move your comment to an answer, i will accept your solution. Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You store `\student`, `\a`, `\b` and `\c\ as unexpanded macros...

Use `\luastring` (instead of `\luastringN`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor} % for 'foreach' loop
\usepackage{xfp} % for '\fpeval'
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{luacode} % for '\luastringN' and '\luaexec' macros
\directlua{ anslist ={}; }

\ExplSyntaxOn
% defining \hide
\cs_set:Npn \hide #1 { 
   \directlua{ table.insert(anslist,\luastring{#1}) }
   \phantom{ #1 }
}
% defining \addanswer
\cs_set:Npn \addanswer #1 {
   \directlua{ table.insert(anslist,\luastring{#1}) }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\def\solutions{
    \luaexec{%
        for i,v in ipairs(anslist) do
            tex.sprint ( v )
        end }
}

\begin{document}
\textbf{questions:}\\

\foreach \student in {student1,student2,student3} {
\edef\a{ \fpeval{(randint(1,9)) } }
\edef\b{ \fpeval{(randint(1,9)) } }
\edef\c{ \fpeval{ \a+\b } }

question for \student: $\a+\b= ?$ \newline
\hide{answer for \student: $\a+\b= \c$ \\[5mm]}

}

\textbf{solutions:}\\

\solutions

\end{document}
```